# Ubuntu Core timedatectl setting incorrect time, config missing servers, cannot be modified and reverts to UCT after a few minutes

Tags: time, ubuntu-core, ntp, nano

Ubuntu core instance starts up with date: `Sun Aug 21 01:31:59 2016` 
(and after trying to correct settings with NTP disabled and reboot, date is: `Wed Nov  2 16:59:29 (LocalTime) 2016`), whereas the actual time was `Sun Oct 15 10:01:01 (LocalTime) 2017`.

This seems to be caused by `timedatectl` trying to set the network time without any servers configured. `sudo cat /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` gives:

```
[Time]  
#NTP=   
#FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
```

<strike>Due to the nature of the core snap, this config file cannot be corrected.</strike>

Changing the date or time, with timedatectl's NTP still active reverts to the incorrect time.
After `set-ntp false` it is possible to correct the date and time, lasting until the next reboot, due to lack of a hardware clock on my test unit.

Setting the time zone to my time zone works correctly, for a few minutes. Initially `timedatectl status` displays the correct timezone after Local Time, but then reverts to UTC. Output from `date` command indicates the local zone so the settings is successful in other areas, only `timedatectl` reports the wrong timezone.

Is this a bug, or am I missing the method to configure this correctly?

*EDIT:* Not being able to edit `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` was an issue with `pinano`, using `vi` I was able to edit the file, will monitor it, but the config should also include a default NTP server, I believe.

---

Output from `snap list`:

```
avahi       0.6.32        44    ondra      - 
core        16-2.28.1     3025  canonical  core 
nextcloud   11.0.4snap1   2713  nextcloud  - 
pi2-kernel  4.4.0-1030-3  22    canonical  kernel 
pi3         16.04-0.5     6     canonical  gadget 
pinano      2.8.7         8     vbota      -
```

Comment: Use code formatting for commands and command output, please: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I believe I have already done so, did I miss something, or was my use excessive?

Comment: The output of `snap list` is an HTML list, the contents of `timesyncd.conf` is a bunch of separate lines separated by `br` tags. Just copy the text here, select it and press Ctrl-K to format, please.

Comment: @muru Ok, changed as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am marking this as answered, seeing as the main issue - the incorrect time from NTP - can be solved by editing with vi.

I am leaving this up here for anyone else experiencing the same issue, since I could not find a reference to the issue anywhere else when I did a search. Also, as I believe there are some minor defects in the tools used, resulting in the problem occurring, and this serves as a note of that.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone reverting in `timedatectl` output seems to be a bug.

The journal has this:

```
systemd-timedated[5870]: /etc/localtime should be a symbolic link to a time zone data file in /usr/share/zoneinfo/.
```

The file is an indirect link:

```
# ls -lah /etc/localtime /etc/writable/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jul 27 20:07 /etc/localtime -> /etc/writable/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 27 10:08 /etc/writable/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/TZContinent/TZCity
```

The `date` command reports the correct time.

Comment: (My NTP seems to be working, so I don't particularly care about the other question)